# QVTKWidget vs QOpenGLWidget

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, vtk

My VTK display is too slow and it's probably because I don't understand the way to use it effectively.

I did also a display using OpenGL and is much faster but it's ugly.

- VTK display (using QVTKWidget):

  In the the communication thread, we connect to our sensor and everytime I get new data, I update a buffer and I call a function that draw the 3D result. One big problem, I receive data much faster than the rendering.
- OpenGL display (QOpenGLWidget):

  In the communication thread, we connect to the sensor and everytime I get new data, I update a buffer.
  In the QT interface thread, the function paintGL() draw the scene with the current buffer values.

In VTK using QVTKWidget, is it possible to do the same logic as my OpenGL display? Do have a function that will draw the scene using a buffer? Like the `paintGL()` function?

Or does anyone can tell me the VTK logic to render a new scene 20 times every second for example?

Example of my program:

```
OnDataReceived()
{
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkRendererCollection> lRC = mVTKWidget->GetRenderWindow()->GetRenderers();
    lRC->InitTraversal();
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderer> lPointsRenderer = lRC->GetNextItem();

    vtkSmartPointer<vtkHexahedron> lHex = vtkSmartPointer<vtkHexahedron>::New();
    // Create a cell array to store the hex in
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkCellArray> lHexs = vtkSmartPointer<vtkCellArray>::New();
    for ( i = 0; i < number_of_objects; ++i)
    {
        // Insert 8 points
        lPoints->InsertNextPoint( ... );
        lHex->GetPointIds()->SetId( ... );
        lHexs->InsertNextCell( lHex );
    }

    vtkSmartPointer<vtkUnstructuredGrid> luGrid = vtkSmartPointer<vtkUnstructuredGrid>::New();
    luGrid->SetPoints( lPoints );
    luGrid->SetCells( VTK_HEXAHEDRON, lHexs );
    luGrid->GetCellData()->SetScalars( lColors );

    // Setup actor and mapper
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkDataSetMapper> lMapper = vtkSmartPointer<vtkDataSetMapper>::New();
    lMapper->SetInputData( luGrid );
    lActor->SetMapper( lMapper );

    lPointsRenderer->AddActor( lActor );
    mVTKWidget->update();
}
```

Is it possible to update the 8 points of each hexahedron instead of rebuilding the scene every time? I have more than 10 000 hexahedron to display updated 20 times per second..

Comment: Easy solution is to use a separate queue, and deliver your updates with it. Or if you only need the latest value, then have the GUI thread fetch the latest value when it is ready to do drawing.

Comment: It's not clear what exactly is this buffer you are talking about. What kind of data are we talking about (point cloud --> the buffer is a vertex buffer?)? Can you post at least the part of code that does the VTK processing of the data?

Comment: If the number and structure (the same hexahedron is made always of the same 8 points) of points does not change, just keep a reference to lPoints outside of OnDataReceived and update the positions only. If their numbers change between frames, but the shape of the hexahedron is the same, you can use glyph rendering (https://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/Filtering/Glyph3D). If you have different shapes and different numbers of points, I am afraid you will be force to rebuild the scene to some extent in each frame.

Comment: The points are always the same but their xyz coordinates are different. The hexahedrons can be bigger but the points will be the same. If I update the xyz points, the scene will update?

Comment: Yes, it will update, just update the points' position and afterwards call luGrid->Modified(); to let the mapper know that the input data changed (and to be sure you can call lMapper->Update() explicitly, although that should happen automatically somewhere down the line). This way you will have to do all the construction only once (the InsertNextPoint/Cell etc.).

Comment: I test it and it's almost working. Is it normal that is slow for over 10000 moving objets? Is it normal that with OpenGL display  is about 10 times faster?